# How to get DNS servers for the active network connection in UWP application?

Tags: c#, dns, uwp

I need to perform DNS queries of different kinds (e.g. DNS MX lookup). For that, I need to auto-detect which DNS servers are associated with the active network connection. All methods I used in Windows applications and .NET Framework don't work with UWP for different reasons (no required classes or NotImplementedException): WMI, Registry, System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces.

I checked Windows.Networking.Connectivity namespace but couldn't find what I need.

Comment: Do you see what you need using a cmd.exe with following command > IPCONFIG/ALL?  If so, you should find what you need a www.pinvoke.net

Comment: Well, I understand I can usually get what I need with WinAPI calls but I first need to make sure I can't do this with .NET code (like I did with normal .NET Framework).

Comment: I'm not sure why Microsoft decided to eliminate method in Net that were available in WinAPI.  I know there were errors in the WinAPI for socket connections and decided to rewrite the socket modes in Net.  I don't know if this applied to the DNS features.  I also know a lot of WinAPIs were eliminated because they couldn't be supported in a managed library.

Comment: You can use one of my libraries https://github.com/MichaCo/DnsClient.NET to run DNS queries. I actually ran into that issue on UWP myself and decided to implemented support with native APIs until MS implements it... Seems to work fine. Check out the latest beta nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces` unfortunately doesn't work yet on UWP, although I'm not exactly sure why this is as the native APIs are available. Maybe I'm missing something.

Anyways, I had the same issue yesterday and ended up using [`GetNetworkParams`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/aa365968(v=vs.85).aspx) from the IpHlpApi. 
At least until Netstandard2.0 might finally have support for those APIs in a managed way...

`GetNetworkParams` gives you the host name and all currently configured DNS Server addresses in one very simple call.

You could also use GetAdaptersAddresses which gives a lot more information and all that (used to populate the `NetworkInterface` managed stuff). But hey, we just need the DNS server right?

From GetNetworkParams you get the [`FIXED_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365900(v=vs.85).aspx) structure which has the (`PIP_ADDR_STRING CurrentDnsServer`) list of dns servers.

If you don't want to implement all that yourself, you can use my [DnsClient.NET library](https://github.com/MichaCo/DnsClient.NET). It uses the stuff mentioned above to initialize with the System's DNS Servers, if you don't specify an IpEndpoint manually.

e.g.

```
var lookup = new LookupClient();
var result = await lookup.QueryAsync("example.com", QueryType.MX);
```

Should just work fine.

Comment: GetNetworkParams worked just fine for UWP app, thanks.

Comment: I turned out GetNetworkParams works only in debug builds. In Release, there is "Unresolved P/Invoke method 'GetNetworkParams!iphlpapi.dll' because it is not available in UWP applications." warning which results in an error when trying to validate the app on uploading to Windows Store.

Comment: @Alex mhm thanks for the update, that's actually bad news -.-